This contains too many questions to be allowed, but can you identify one that is okay?
We might suspect that the principle of mathematical induction is just one example of a possibly large number of similar principles.  In particular, the principle of mathematical induction, in one formulation, involves a very simple sequential ordering of the set of positive integers.  Can we generalize to other orderings?
Suppose that we describe some set S such that:
(1) each of infinitely many elements of S is a sequence of positive integers, and in particular a permutation of the set of positive integers, and
(2) some elements of S may be a permutation of a proper subset of the set of positive integers, and
(3) there are no other elements of S
First Question:
Given a unique characterization of some such set S, could it be that the statement "No element of S is a permutation of a proper subset of the set of positive integers" is independent of ZFC?
Second Question:
Is there a description that uniquely determines some such set S, such that if ZFC is consistent, then "No element of S is a permutation of a proper subset of the set of positive integers" is independent of ZFC, and when we augment ZFC by conjoining with ZFC (or appending to ZFC) the sentence  "No element of S is a permutation of a proper subset of the set of positive integers", then the resulting augmented set theory resolves at least one conjecture in number theory that is independent of ZFC?
Introduction to Third Question:
Given some outline of ideas for augmenting ZFC with additional axioms, we could figuratively imagine an infinite printout of all possible proofs of logical consequences of the premises of ZFC, and we can imagine that introducing an interesting axiom (or strictly speaking "sub-axiom") may be (figuratively speaking) too much like introducing a new global variable in a computer program: maybe there's a collision somewhere.  In other words, we may wish to consider a local sub-axiom that is assumed only within one specified axiom.
Third Question:
Is there an existing system of mathematical logic that already permits the formulation of a conjecture that contains within it a local sub-axiom?  Alternatively, is there a framework within which systems of mathematical logic can be introduced and explained (both formally, using very general principles that apply to a wide variety of different systems of mathematical logic, and informally, using protocols for ordinary human communication), and that allows for the formulation of a conjecture that contains within it a local sub-axiom?
A bit of terminology might enable a bit of exploration or a common language for formulating and understanding an answer to the "Third Question."  We could write a conjecture C as follows:
"(D subject to A & B)" where we will explicitly or implicitly impose some restriction on D, so that there will be no way to deduce A from "(D subject to A & B)", and no way to deduce B from "(D subject to A & B)".  The sub-axioms A and B are local to the sentence "(D subject to A & B)."

Why not post the first question on its own? The answers you get might enable you to sharpen or otherwise improve the remaining questions.

@GerryMyerson Is that a suggestion, or just a question? I'm wondering whether you refer to "the first question" because of its content, or because it happens to be the one that I gave the label "First Question" to.  I agree with you about the answers: they might enable [etc.] ..., but do you agree that there might be no answers, and only a progressively down-voted non-meta question until it is closed?

You'll never know how a question will be received, until you post it.
